# Web scraping for project in school

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from a page using Selenium. I did it last week, but something changed this week and now it doesn't work anymore. The problem is "show more" button, or "Prikaži broj" as you can see on website. I have multiple pages to scrape but let's focus on one.

Code is:

```
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Nenad/chromedriver', options=options)
driver.get('https://www.nekretnine.rs/stambeni-objekti/stanovi/zvezdara-konjarnik-milica-rakica-57m2-milica-rakica/NkJXDiY2ugE/')
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.row:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(2) > button:nth-child(2)').click()
    sleep(randint(3, 5))
    home_phone = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.row:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(1)')
    condo_agency_cell_phones.append(home_phone.text)
except:
    condo_agency_cell_phones.append('NaN')
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.row:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(4) > button:nth-child(2)').click()
    sleep(randint(3, 5))
    cell_phone = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.row:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(4) > span:nth-child(1)')
    condo_agency_cell_phones.append(cell_phone.text)
except:
    condo_agency_cell_phones.append('NaN')
driver.close()
```

Last week it worked with xpath, but now it doesn't. I even found a button but it doesn't click:

```
options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Nenad/chromedriver', options=options)
driver.get('https://www.nekretnine.rs/stambeni-objekti/stanovi/zvezdara-konjarnik-milica-rakica-57m2-milica-rakica/NkJXDiY2ugE/')
sleep(20)
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button\[@type='button'\]").click()
    print(element.text)
except:
    print('NaN')
```

Comment: There are multiple "Prikaži broj" buttons on the page, which one are you trying to click ?

Comment: Sameer, just 2 buttons for showing home phone and cell phone, Katherine answered for first button, ill figure out how to do second.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of xpath, try finding by css selector `find_element_by_css_selector(button[type="button"])`

Answer (score 0):

If the first answer did not solve your issue try this. Imported some different libraries. In your code above the "try:" was returning an error for undefined variables because the libraries were not imported.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from time import sleep
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Nenad/chromedriver', options=options)
# driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\\Py\\geckodriver.exe');

driver.get('https://www.nekretnine.rs/stambeni-objekti/stanovi/zvezdara-konjarnik-milica-rakica-57m2-milica-rakica/NkJXDiY2ugE/')
condo_agency_cell_phones = []
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.row:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(2) > button:nth-child(2)').click()
    # sleep(randint(3, 5))
    sleep(4)
    # home_phone1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div[11]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form[1]/span")
    # condo_agency_cell_phones.append(home_phone1.text)
    home_phone = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.row:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(1)')
    print(home_phone.text)
    condo_agency_cell_phones.append(home_phone.text)
except:
    condo_agency_cell_phones.append('NaN')
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.row:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(4) > button:nth-child(2)').click()
    # sleep(randint(3, 5))
    sleep ( 4 )
    cell_phone = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.row:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(4) > span:nth-child(1)')
    condo_agency_cell_phones.append(cell_phone.text)
except:
    condo_agency_cell_phones.append('NaN')

print(condo_agency_cell_phones)
driver.close()
```